# JQuery Functions and how they are working together (after() , $(this).next().html())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm using a function in JQuery, but i dont understand completly how it's works,maybe someone can give me a hand?

```
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
    $(this).attr("src", "Imgs/minus.png");
});
$("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "Imgs/plus.png");
    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
});
```

What this means? i mean in details. ^^"

```
 $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: It searches for the next `<tr>` in your html code and will append  the provided code after the `<tr>`.
You really should start reading the jquery-documentation. Those methods are explained there pretty good ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it apart.

```
$(this)
```

Refers to this element, i.e. the element that was clicked on.

```
.closest("tr")
```

From that element, go up the DOM tree to find the closest element matching the `tr` selector (i.e. a `<tr>` element)

```
.after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
```

And add this HTML after it.

```
$(this).next().html()
```

Means take `this` element, find the `next` one, and return its `html`.

---

It all basically means *add another row to the table with two cells, one empty and the other with a colspan of 999, and inside of it add the HTML of the element after the one that just got clicked*.